# how to get rows only when any of the rows are true in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({"col1":[True,False,False,True,False],
              "col2":[False,True,False,True,False],
               "col3":[Null,True,True,True,False],
               "Cnt" :[1,2,3,4,5]})
```

I only want to get row only when either col1 or col2 is True i.e. row 2 and 4 will going to get  eliminated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in `col1` and `col2` are boolean only chain both columns by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
df[df["col1"] & df["col2"]]
```

Or filter columns for test by subset `["col1","col2"]` and test by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df[df[["col1","col2"]].all(axis=1)]
```

If possible mixed values - boolean and some another values test `True`s:

```
df[df["col1"].eq(True) & df["col2"].eq(True)]
```

If possible boolean are string repr:

```
df[df["col1"].eq('True') & df["col2"].eq('True')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
df1[df1[["col1","col2"]].all(axis=1)]
```

Else you can run it based out of a single column as well

```
if all(df1['col1']):
   print("All True")
else:
   print("Not All True")
```